# jQuery addCss and .removeCss only works on page refresh

Tags: jquery, navbar, superfish

To the unordered list

```
<ul class="sf-navbar sf-menu" id="sfmenu">
```

I am using following jQuery code but it works only on page refresh.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $('#sfmenu').removeClass( "nav navbar-nav" ).addClass('sf-navbar sf-menu');
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('#sfmenu' ).addClass( "nav navbar-nav" ).removeClass( "sf-navbar sf-menu" );
    }
});
```

I also tried with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $('#sfmenu').removeClass( "nav navbar-nav" );
        $('#sfmenu').addClass('sf-navbar sf-menu');
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('#sfmenu' ).addClass( "nav navbar-nav" );
        $('#sfmenu' ).removeClass( "sf-navbar sf-menu" );
    }
});
```

But no success.

Also I tried with UL as

```
   <ul class="" id="sfmenu">
```

But still no success. Suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: How did you trigger the event?

Comment: What if the screen is 768px?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [$(window).resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) like,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   function sfmenuToggle() {
      if ($(window).width() > 768) {
          $('#sfmenu').removeClass( "nav navbar-nav" )
                      .addClass('sf-navbar sf-menu');
      }
      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
          $('#sfmenu' ).addClass( "nav navbar-nav" )
                       .removeClass( "sf-navbar sf-menu" );
      }
    }
    // on window resize
    $(window).resize(function(){
        sfmenuToggle();
    });
    // on page load
    sfmenuToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only running the code on the `.ready` event, i.e. when the page completes loading.

Try binding `$(window).on('resize', function () { ...` in addition.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need window resize event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() > 768) 
        $('#sfmenu').removeClass( "nav navbar-nav" ).addClass('sf-navbar sf-menu');
      else
        $('#sfmenu' ).addClass( "nav navbar-nav" ).removeClass( "sf-navbar sf-menu" );
  }).resize();//to trigger on ready
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $('#sfmenu').removeClass( "nav navbar-nav" ).addClass('sf-navbar sf-menu');
}
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('#sfmenu' ).addClass( "nav navbar-nav" ).removeClass( "sf-navbar sf-menu" );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes thats because your applying the css classes only when Dom is loaded, which happens only once, irrespective of whether window is resized or not.  may be you need to add check the window size in `window re-size` event.

Following is a simple demo of window re-size event, try re-sizing the window on JSfiddle to understand the effects.

**JS Code:**

```
$(function () {
 $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $('p').removeClass("green").addClass('red');
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('p').removeClass("red").addClass("green");
    }
 });
});
```

**Live demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dCug7/51/show**